# How to draw same edge name by JUNG2

Tags: java, jung2

I am doing a draw network topology project by JUNG2, now found JUNG2 couldn't draw same edge(name) on different vertex. And report follow:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: edge GigabitEthernet0/3<--->GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0 already exists in this graph with endpoints <HKBR1, HKBR3> and cannot be added with endpoints <HKBR2, HKBR4>
at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.AbstractGraph.getValidatedEndpoints(AbstractGraph.java:93)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseMultigraph.addEdge(SparseMultigraph.java:123)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.AbstractGraph.addEdge(AbstractGraph.java:60)
at pkg.DrawnTopology.DrawnTopology(DrawnTopology.java:45)
at pkg.ReadLine.main(ReadLine.java:85)
```

I had stored all edge and vertex to a two-dimensional array. Two-dimensional array data learn from different files, so data is dynamic. Due to network topology maybe have same edge name, so how to resolve that?

Comment: Please provide minimal code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ace, Sorry, I will attention in future, as Marco13's respond, simple code can reproduce the alarm:

`g.addEdge("edge0", v0, v1);`
`g.addEdge("edge0", v2, v3);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question clearly lacks details, but from the description and error message, one can probably guess what's wrong here:

Your graph may be defined to be a `Graph<V, String>`.

<sub>It may be a subclass of `Graph`, and the vertex type does not matter. The crucial point is that the edge type is `String`)</sub>

And you are attempting to add edges to the graph like this:

```
g.addEdge("edge0", v0, v1);
g.addEdge("edge0", v2, v3);
```

This will cause an error, because the edge `"edge0"` exists twice. (And this makes sense. Otherwise: What should happen when you ask the graph for the endpoints of `"edge0"`? Should it return `v0,v1` or `v2,v3`? It's simply ambiguous).

(Note that this is not only the case when the edge type is `String`. It will happen for *any* edge type, as long as two edges are `equal` to each other).

One simple solution here is to introduce a dedicated `Edge` class that wraps the String:

```
class Edge
{
    private final String name;

    Edge(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This class does **not** have its `equals` method overridden. So two objects of this type will **not** be equal, even when the Strings are equal:

```
Edge e0 = new Edge("edge0");
Edge e1 = new Edge("edge0");
System.out.println(e0.equals(e1)); // prints "false"
```

The edge labels can then simply be the `toString` representations of these edges, which return the original string.

An example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.FRLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;

class Edge
{
    private final String name;

    Edge(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public class JungDuplicateEdgesTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        final Graph<String, Edge> g = getGraph();
        VisualizationViewer<String, Edge> vv = 
            new VisualizationViewer<String, Edge>(
                new FRLayout<String, Edge>(g));

        class EdgeLabelTransformer implements Transformer<Edge, String>
        {
            @Override
            public String transform(Edge edge)
            {
                return edge.toString();
            }
        }
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(
            new EdgeLabelTransformer());

        jf.getContentPane().add(vv);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static Graph<String, Edge> getGraph()
    {
        Graph<String, Edge> g = new DirectedSparseGraph<String, Edge>();
        g.addVertex("v0");
        g.addVertex("v1");
        g.addEdge(new Edge("e0"), "v0", "v1");
        g.addEdge(new Edge("e0"), "v1", "v0");
        return g;
    }
}
```

---

A side note: It could, for some applications, make sense to store the vertices of the edge in the `Edge` class as well. Then you could implement the `equals` and `hashCode` method in a way that allows you treating two edges as equal when they have the same vertices.

Comment: Marco13, very thanks your kindly respond!!!

Base on your code, JUNG2 should use physical address to check whether one edge equal another edge, so use a new object and return same edge name by toString(), although two edge have same name, physical address different (as you test)! Very cool solution! I will change my code.

Due to I am no 15 reputation, so couldn't vote up your answer...

Comment: Hi, Marco13, more one question, how to transfer two-dimensional array from other class to getGraph()? E.g: `g.addEdge(test[2][x], test[0][x], test[1][x]); `

Comment: @frank It does not really use the "physical address". It uses the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of the class. (But when these methods are not overridden, then yes, they can be imagined to use some sort of "physical address"). Second question: That depends on how and where your graph is constructed. You already **had** some place where your graph was built. In doubt, you don't have to change too much - only the edge type parameter, and instead of your old `g.add(test[2][x], ...)` you write `g.add(new Edge(test[2][x]), ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the edge names have to be unique but you can manipulate what is shown in your graph. To get unique names for edges I use the following pattern for names of edges: fromVertex_edgeName_toVertex.

You then need an `EdgeLabelTransformer`:

```
private class EdgeLabelTransformer<V> implements Transformer<V, String> {

    @Override
    public String transform(V v) {
        return v.toString().substring(v.toString().indexOf("_") + 1, v.toString().lastIndexOf("_"));
    }
}
```

This transformer actually tells the `VisualViewer` what to display. So in my case it just displays the middle part which results in that you can have multiple edges with the same displayed name in your graph.

Add the transformer like this:

```
visualViewer.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new EdgeLabelTransformer<String>());
```

Comment: Hi, Moh-Aw, thanks your respond!  Due to edge name so long now (e.g GigabitEthernet0/3<--->GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0), so add other String to edge name not good way.